# Chrome: Open links to OpenOffice documents on WebDAV directly in OpenOffice

Tags: google-chrome, webdav, openoffice-writer

is there any way to open OpenOffice with the URL when I click on the link in Chrome browser?

To be a bit more precise: I have a WebDAV folder that contains documents.

```
  https://myserver/documents/doc1.odt
  https://myserver/documents/doc1.odt
```

I can open (and modify and store) these documents via open the file using the open dialog in openoffice with these URLs.

But what I really want is to embed these links into my webpage and when I click onto this links I want the document behind it to be opened in OpenOffice.

I'm looking for these feature within Chrome browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some research and finally used firebreath (http://www.firebreath.org/) to create a native NPAPI plugin and to use it in  my own extension.

I'm open for suggestions and discussion about this at https://github.com/magomi/OOCaller

Comment: Any additional information on what you actually did to fix the problem?  The link just goes to stubs for building a Chrome plugin, not your solution for the WebDAV issue.

Comment: The repo has the plugin on linux (https://github.com/magomi/OOCaller/tree/master/linux/OOCaller). The plugin is **very simple**. It provides a method _callOO(webDavDocumentPath)_ to be used within javascript. This method will execute a system call and opens OpenOffice with the document path at the webdav server as a parameter. Check /firebreath_project/OOCaller/OOCallerAPI.cpp for the implementation of the method. The current code was sufficient for a showcase. By now I'm working on a version that could be proper configured (set OO executable,...).

Answer (score 2):

There's a webdav nsapi plugin at http://code.google.com/p/npapi-msdocs/

Comment: Note than Office 2016 for Mac dropped support for WebDav and hence this plugin will no longer function with it.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension for Chrome (SimpleGet) that has a plugin for Windows and Linux that can execute an app with command line parameters.....
    http://pinel.cc/
    http://code.google.com/p/simple-get/
    http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/simple-get/